# Generating List of All Scrabble Tiles in Python

Tags: python, list, function, loops

I am trying to print a list of all the Scrabble tiles you would find in a bag. I have to use a function and I have two variables, one for LETTERS and another one for COUNT (the number tiles each letter has) when I print it it is printing every letter 26 times :(

```
def genRepeatedChars(chars, repeats) :
    tileBag = []
    for LETTERS in allLetters:
       for i in range(len(COUNTS)):
           print (LETTERS)
    return chars
```

Comment: Something seems off in your code. What is `tileBag` and why isn't it being used? Your function is getting two arguments `chars` and `repeats` but neither are being used; instead two variables `allLetters` and `COUNTS` are being used without being declared...

Comment: sorry i should have been more clear, COUNTS and allLetters are global variables which are defined at the beginning of the program.

Comment: And what about `tileBag`, `chars` and `repeats`? It would also help if you could share how `allLetters` and `COUNTS` are being declared. Plus I still think the code you put here contains a mistake, so please double check to make sure you typed it here correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your variables `LETTERS` and `COUNT` are *lists* (which seems likely as it's printing each letter 26 times), you can print them like this:

```
LETTERS = list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
COUNT = [2, 4, 9, 14, 9, 7, 1, 14, 7, 3, 11, 10, 8, 14, 14, 4, 4, 15, 14, 8, 2, 3, 4, 7, 10, 1]
for letter, count in zip(LETTERS, COUNT):
    print('{}: {}'.format(letter, count))
```

**Output**

```
A: 2
B: 4
C: 9
D: 14
E: 9
F: 7
G: 1
H: 14
I: 7
J: 3
K: 11
L: 10
M: 8
N: 14
O: 14
P: 4
Q: 4
R: 15
S: 14
T: 8
U: 2
V: 3
W: 4
X: 7
Y: 10
Z: 1
```

If you want to create a "tile bag" you can do this:

```
from collections import Counter
from random import shuffle

tile_bag = list(Counter(dict(zip(LETTERS,COUNT))).elements())
shuffle(tile_bag)
```

which will give you a bag of random tiles. You can select a random tile with:

```
tile = tile_bag.pop()
```